# Javascript: Download image from img tag which's src url supports only one time request and Tainted by crossOrigin

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, canvas

I have an image in my html dom

[image: image picture]

(the green border image) it has a `img` tag and having a src url.
I've tried with `fetch` by retrieving blob but request isn't supporting second request. Server is refusing to get image for second time.
So I've tried with `canvas` with

```
ctx.drawImage(imgNode, 0,0)
```

and tried placing it in dom. The canvas copies the image.
[image: copied canvas]

But when I tried getting `toDataURL` and `getImageData`

it shows following errors.
[image]

Later, I tried with `imgnode.crossOrigin = 'anonymouse'`
But then Image breaks.

[image: broken image]

I've checked by `right click > copy image` Then I can paste image somewhere else.
So how am I supposed to save this image/copy this image in my local disk.
I'm using selenium with python. I want to retrieve image.

Comment: just FYI - `bellow` = `"a deep roaring shout or sound"` whereas `below` = `"extending underneath"` etc

Comment: Im sorry my english isn't that good

Comment: perfectly OK - just thought you'd like to know

Comment: So can I get some solutions to current problems sir please

Comment: You have not provided sufficient code to reproduce the problem ( or any code actually ) so nobody will really be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this javascript code on the page and create an alert(). You can change the `"image/jpeg"` to png or as it is.

```js
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); 
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
}

alert(getBase64Image(document.getElementById("ImgCaptcha")))
```

2. In your application, make a listener to the alert and capture the base64 image value.

Comment: I've tried this already it gives following error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported`

Comment: I've tried with `crossOrigin` as `anonymous` as well but you can see from last screenshot it immediately breaks the image

Comment: ohh. no idea then.